# Building an ecommerce site using Laravel: How do I view/route products based on their ID?

Tags: php, laravel

I followed a tutorial on Tutsplus about creating an ecommerce website using Laravel. The problem I'm having right now is when trying to route to a subfolder. In the tutorial, the instructor included a feature where you can view products by ID. And this is how he did it:

```
// StoreController.php
public function getView($id) {
    return View::make('store.view')->with('store', Store::find($id));
}
```

This piece of code seems to be passing an `id` from the `stores` table. I think when a product is clicked, that's when the `id` is passed

```
// Routes.php
Route::controller('store', 'StoreController');
```

Also some of the templates:

```
// store\index.blade.php
<h2>Stores</h2>
<hr>
<div id="stores row">
    @foreach($stores as $store)
    <div class="stores col-md-3">
        <a href="/store/products/view/{{ $store->id }}">
            {{ HTML::image($store->image, $store->title, array('class' => 'feature', 'width'=>'240', 'height' => '127')) }}
        </a>

        <h3><a href="/store/products/view/{{ $store->id }}">{{ $store->title }}</a></h3>

        <p>{{ $store->description }}</p>
    </div>
    @endforeach
</div><!-- end product -->
```

So.. How it goes is when I click on a product, it leads me to `domain:8000/store/view/6` where `6` is the `id`.

This works fine but what I want to know is how do I route through a subfolder? Let's say I want it to be like this: `store/view/products/6` considering that I have a folder called products and my view.blade.php is inside that like this: `store/products/view`.

In my `StoreController` class, I tried changing this

```
public function getView($id) {
    return View::make('store.view')->with('store', Store::find($id));
}
```

to this

```
public function getView($id) {
    return View::make('store.product.view')->with('store', Store::find($id));
}
```

but it does not seem to work giving me nothing but a Controller Method Not Found Error.

Comment: look the instructor is using controller routes so you actually don't have control over naming  the links, naming the routes and changing controller functions associated. The url will remain the same and if you have the view file at the location, you will notice it getting loaded correctly with your code.

Comment: Take a look here: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the view name `View::make('store.product.view')` has nothing to do with the URL.

You have to change the route:

```
Route::controller('store/view', 'StoreController');
```

And then adjust the name of your method in the controller because it should be the same as the segment of the URL after `store/view`

```
public function getProducts($id) {
    return View::make('store.product.view')->with('store', Store::find($id));
}
```

I strongly recommend you read the [Laravel docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing) on the topic